# Plot two columns for 1000 rows with different color

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have two features `datetime` and `volt` for `1000 machineIDs`. I am printing datetime and volt using matplotlib. Now, some `machineIDs` have unique values like there are 6-7 unique lines and hence there are multiple lines on the graph. Like this,

[image]

I want to segregate these lines in different colors for different `machineIDs`. Problem is I am plotting for `datetime` and `volt` only . So how do I do this?

Here is a sample data

```
machineID   dt_truncated    volt_rollingmean_12   label_e
964      2015-01-27 12:00:00    194.788225          1
```

Here I am plotting b/w volt and dt_truncated based on value of label_e. If label_e is1, then we consider it for plot. But there are 1000 machine IDs and because of that there are 6-7 different lines on plot.

As per the answer by quest I am getting this plot

[image]

Comment: Sharing a small snipper of sample data will be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: @quest added sinppet data with some explanation

Comment: Should each line on graph represent exactly one machine id?

Comment: not exactly.. there are 5-6 different lines representing machineIDs there and each should be in different color

Comment: So each point on one line should represent different machine_id?

Comment: Not each point, there are 6-7 lines on plot like at a particular datetime you can see there are 2-3 values for volt, so each line should represent one MachineID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can go about it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
groups = df.groupby('machineID')
for name, group in groups:
    group = group.sort_values("dt_truncated")
    ax.plot(group.dt_truncated, group.volt_rollingmean_12, marker='o',  ms=12, label=group.machineID.unique()[0])
ax.legend()
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: I am getting something different. I have added that plot in question as edit. Please check.

Comment: Because our data are different, mine is random.

Comment: Btw, what is `ms` in here? Is it measure?

Comment: `ms` abbreviation for `markersize`

Comment: Also @quest how do I increase the plot size? Will `plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))` this work?

Comment: Also @quest since there are different lines here, to identify which machineID it is representing, how to I add legend to this plot? Please tell.

Comment: To change the figure size `fig.set_figheight(15); fig.set_figwidth(15)` or `f, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(15,15))` should also work.

Comment: `ax.legend()` will bring out the legend.

Comment: Modified the answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Pivot your dataframe before plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dti = pd.date_range('2021-12-20', '2021-12-26')
df = pd.DataFrame({'machineID': np.repeat(range(1, 6), len(dti)), 
                   'dt_truncated': dti.tolist()*5,
                   'volt_rollingmean_12': np.random.randint(160, 380, 5*len(dti))})

df.pivot('dt_truncated', 'machineID', 'volt_rollingmean_12').plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

To filter on `label_e`:

```
df[df['label_e'] == 1].pivot(...).plot()
```

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to pass a column instead of date range? You hard coded date range.

Comment: The only relevant part is `df[df['label_e'] == 1].pivot('dt_truncated', 'machineID', 'volt_rollingmean_12').plot()`.

Comment: I created this dataframe because you don't give any data (one line is not sufficient) Check [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).